# Prevent stack trace leak in production in Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, express

I was looking at [this](https://github.com/gothinkster/node-express-realworld-example-app/blob/master/app.js) Nodejs express Guthub repo. The production strack trace leak prevention is done using:

```
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (!isProduction) {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err.stack);

    res.status(err.status || 500);

    res.json({'errors': {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    }});
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({'errors': {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  }});
});
```

I do not understand why the production strack trace middleware does not have to be inside the else condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you shared, an else block would probably make things a bit more clear, but it's not strictly needed. If `isProduction` is truthy, the error handling middleware inside the `if` block will handle the error. Since it does not call `next(err);` to pass the request to the next middleware, control will *not* be passed to the following "production" error-handling middleware. The response is sent and Express is done handling this particular request.

If `isProduction` is falsey, obviously the "development" middleware is not ever registered with Express and all errors will be handled in the "production" error-handler.

The above example, however, would break down if you needed to add another error-handling middleware after the "production" error-handler or something.

**More Details**

In Express, middlewares are run sequentially in the order in which they were registered and control is passed to the next middleware by using the calling the `next` parameter. See the documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application).

[Error handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling), like the ones posted in your example, work the same way. The error will reach these middlewares because a previous middleware called `next` and passed an error like so: `next(new Error('Something went wrong));`.